# How do I get my shell script to reference the programs I see in git bash?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I have a script on my windows computer called `run.sh` with a shebang `#!/bin/bash`

Within this script the command `docker` is invoked.

In my git bash shell, I can use docker and when I say `which docker` I see `/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker`

However when I run the script I immediately get `docker: command not found`

I'm guessing this is because the shell referenced `/bin/bash` is a different shell than I'm using when I'm in git bash.

My question is this: how do I get this to work?

- could I change the shebang to point to whatever shell I use in git bash?
- would it make more sense to configure `/bin/bash` better? How does one figure out which profile or whatnot a given shell installation references?

Edit: Removing the shebang altogether still leaves me with the same error. I think I am conceptualizing this wrong; any "here's a better question" pointers would be very appreciated!

Comment: You might try using the full path to the `docker` executable in your script.

Comment: you can add a startup file to set `PATH` for /bin/bash to the same as git bash is using

Comment: for just the script, you can edit it to use the full path to docker, or you can append desired extra paths to `PATH`. look at the value git bash uses to see what you may want to add

Comment: Why do you need git bash? What's wrong with Cygwin/MSYS2/WSL?

Comment: From which shell are you starting `run.sh`? How do you start it? We are talking about several shells here: The one in which you enter the run.sh command, and the one which is used to execute the run.sh command. Further, how is PATH set inside the shell from which you execute run.sh?